# Help identifying titanium frame based on serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, titanium, serial-number

I’m looking for help identifying the manufacturer of a titanium frame MTB, presumably from the 90’s. It has rim brakes, 26” wheels, and the bottom of the bottom bracket shell is stamped with “Made in USA” and serial B191032. No sign of a make/model.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your time! Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle SE. please add pictures to your question (edit it). Serial numbers rarely, if ever identify a bike.  Pictures of a headtube logo (or any other logo, unique feature), frame, dropouts, etc. can help. A serial number is just a number.

Comment: Based on the above info I have determined it is a 90’s Kona Hei Hei or King Kahuna. Still working on the year of manufacture, but the serial number will confirm it. More to follow…

Comment: @user71663 How did you figure that out? If you can explain that in a reasonable way, don't forget to make it an answer. Just for visibility and scoring points, indeed. ;-)

Comment: I searched for “titanium mtb frame USA” in eBay and found a Kona with a bottom bracket shell marked “Made in USA B18054.” The (unremarkable) frame looks the same otherwise. That’s enough confirmation for my purposes (i.e. to satisfy my curiosity, not for marketing/resale purposes).

Comment: https://www.retrobike.co.uk/threads/kona-titanium-serial-number-list-update-05-09-23.464733/

Comment: Niiice! Thanks for that great Kona serial number resource, Noise. I appreciate the lead!